# facebook iframe app is blank when using https

Tags: facebook, iis

I'm using a self generated SSL certificate on my localhost IIS and pointed my facebook sercure Iframe app URL to https:\localhost but just get a blank page. 
when browsing to it not within FB, it gives me the cert warning and then after i add it as an exception, it goes through to the site fine.

using http:\localhost for the non-secure url works fine

any ideas why i'm getting the blank page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know FB checks your certificate and if it not valid it just wont load your app in the iframe. You can try this service that seams to be intended to exactly this kind of problems: http://www.social-server.com/.

> Don't stress if you can't afford an SSL certificate for Facebook's SSL migration...
>   ...Use this FREE service to adapt your Facebook pages so that it's viewable over an HTTPS connection.

Comment: And this probably will be [Platform Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) violation (II.5, II.6, II.7 and maybe II.3 and II.4 too), I would recommend get advise from a company lawyer, before using such service.

Comment: Yes it might. You can also try getting a free ssl cert from [comodo](http://www.comodo.com/e-commerce/ssl-certificates/free-ssl-cert.php) but you'll need a fully qualified domain name to get one.

Comment: Or it might also be that your server is not aware of https requests. Did you set your server for https?